# What is the centripetal force acting on the bob of a simple pendulum?

Tags: forces, centripetal-force

[image: SP]

One might say that the tension force $T$ is the centripetal force, but $T$ has been already cancelled out by $mg\cos\theta$. So, either the tension force has been balanced/cancelled by $mg\cos\theta$ or the tension force is greater than $mg\cos\theta$:

$$T-mg\cos\theta=0...(i)$$

$$T-mg\cos\theta=\frac{mv^2}{L}...(ii)$$

Which of (i) and (ii) is correct?

**PS**: My book thinks (i) is correct. So, is my book wrong?

Comment: [See if this helps](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245223/what-keeps-a-pendulum-moving-in-a-circular-path?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your (ii) of course.

The reason the book disregards this factor is because the centripetal force is always directly along the pendulum, thus will not affect the swing rate or acceleration or any aspect of the visible behavior of the pendulum at all.

This is because your book is looking at a very simplified form of the pendulum, where the base is immovably fixed. (among several other simplifications, like assuming no fiction, uniform gravity, no bending resistance or elasticity in the thread, etc)